# Database for large application

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, server

I'm working on an application which will serve about 11,000 new rows in the database per day and approximately 800-1000 queries per second (thats a rough estimate) in the working hours. After the working hours the rate of queries per second will drop to 100-150 per second.

The application has a both web and desktop version and the web version along with the database will be hosted on a dedicated server with 32/64 GBs of RAM and a Intel Xeon E5 1650V3 12 Threads x 3.5 Ghz, everything on 240 GB Intel SSD x 2.

Which database will be best to use for this application? I'm considering MS SQL Server at the moment but what do you think which databse will give me the BEST performance. The database is efficiently designed and the hardware for it's hosting is good as well, everything is hosted on SSDs with a decent amount of RAM and Processing Power (This is the only reason for mentioning the server specifications).

So what are your recommendations, MS SQL Server, Oracle DB, MySQL PostgrSQL or anything else?

Thank you :)

Comment: The one that you know better. And if you ask such a questions - you will fail solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both SQL Server and Oracle should easily be able to handle what you need with that hardware.  When used properly, there's no significant performance difference between the two.

You should focus more on the knowledge/skillset of the people who will be developing & maintaining the system.